# Linux command shell script

Tags: linux, file, awk, command, echo

I am searching in linux logs file which have some error code I wants to calculate these code on hourly basis but my requirement is that response code should be show in below form . In attach file data is not fullfill my requirement can anybody help on this .  My current command

for sample logs -:

```
IP web.com - [01/Aug/2023:01:27:21 +0200] "POST /aa/v1/bbb/session?device_id=urn:uuid:2972033-34a4-4d1c-8ctt-55d31140c09d HTTP/1.1" 503 0 "-" "IOS/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; ttw Build/OTT 1.171019.011)"
```

code -:

```
for i in {00..23} ; do  grep "pattern" access.log |grep "03/Aug/2023:$i" |awk -F " " '{print $4,$9}' |awk '{print $NF}'|sort |uniq -c ; done
 91 200
  1 429
 46 200
  1 503
 11 200
  4 200
  7 200
  9 200
 37 200
  1 403
```

in this output getting response code counts, but i wants one more column which have hours before this above data . for example

```
  hrs   Counts  Response code 
 00    91 200
 00    1 429
 01    46 200
 01    1 503
 02   11 200
```

Hrs  counts error code  in respective column[text]([this is my current output but it is not working for me I wants the data as I shown example above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDF80.jpg) )

Comment: Welcome to SO. Posting an image of code doesn't help; also, the input that you want to process and the result you're expecting aren't clear.

Comment: Please come up with a more meaningful Subject for your question than "Linux command shell script" so other people with a similar question in future can find it.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other ["Asking" topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: could you please check again my cli command to extract the data from raw log file .

Logs raw file sample.

IP web.com - [01/Aug/2023:01:27:21 +0200] "POST /aa/v1/bbb/session?device_id=urn:uuid:2972033-34a4-4d1c-8ctt-55d31140c09d HTTP/1.1" 503 0 "-" "IOS/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; ttw Build/OTT 1.171019.011)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v pattern="some pattern" -v day='01/Aug/2023' '
    $0 ~ pattern && $4 ~ day {
        split($4,a,":")
        codes[a[2]" "$9]++
    }
    END{
        for (i in codes){
            split(i,b)
            print b[1], codes[i], b[2]
        }
    }
' access.log

01 4 503
02 1 200
02 1 404
02 2 503
03 1 200
```

Comment: this code working but not in expecting way , you are just grep the time and pick up the  response code only but i have need of another pattern "grep "pattern" access.log , please check my above command . hope so you understand my expectations .

Comment: @user3318024: ok i didn't see `grep "pattern" access.log`. Check my update